# What can cause Phong specular shading to produce gamut overflows?

Tags: c++, reflection, overflow, raytracing

I am currently implementing a basic raytracer in c++. Works pretty well so far, matte materials (with ambient and diffuse brdf) work as expected so far.

Adding specular highlights would result in the full [Phong Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading) and that's exactly what i tried to do.

Unfortunately, i encounter gamut overflow, with all kinds of values for the specular reflection constant ks and the exponent. Here are some examples.

```
// Sphere material definition:
ka    = 0.9;
kd    = 1.0;
ks    = 0.3;
exp   = 1.0;
color = rgb(1.0, 1.0, 0.98);
```

image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/614366/cornell_1.png

```
// Sphere material definition:
ka    = 0.9;
kd    = 1.0;
ks    = 0.3;
exp   = 20.0;                  // only changed exp
color = rgb(1.0, 1.0, 0.98);
```

image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/614366/cornell_2.png

```
// Sphere material definition:
ka    = 0.9;
kd    = 1.0;
ks    = 0.1;                  // only changes here
exp   = 0.1;                  // and here
color = rgb(1.0, 1.0, 0.98);
```

image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/614366/cornell_3.png

and here are some relevant excerpts of the code:

in raycast.cpp

```
namespace {
    const float floatmax = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
}

rgb
RayCast::trace ( const Ray& ray ) const
{
    HitRecord rec(scene_ptr_);
    float tmax = floatmax;
    float tmin = 0.0;

    if ( scene_ptr_->shapes.hit(ray,tmin,tmax,rec) )
    {
        rec.ray = ray;
        return rec.material_ptr->shade(rec);
    }

    return scene_ptr_->bgcolor;
}
```

in phong.cpp

```
rgb
Phong::shade ( HitRecord& hitrec ) const
{
    Vector wo = - hitrec.ray.dir();

    rgb L = ambient_brdf_ptr_->rho(hitrec,wo) *
        hitrec.scene_ptr->ambient_ptr->L(hitrec);

    int num_lights = hitrec.scene_ptr->lights.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < num_lights; ++i)
    {
        Vector wi     = hitrec.scene_ptr->lights[i]->get_direction(hitrec);
        float  ndotwi = dot(hitrec.normal, wi);

        if ( ndotwi > 0.0 )
        {
            L += ( diffuse_brdf_ptr_->f (hitrec, wo, wi)  +
                   specular_brdf_ptr_->f(hitrec, wo, wi)
                 ) * hitrec.scene_ptr->lights[i]->L(hitrec) * ndotwi;
        }
    }

    return L;
}
```

in specular.cpp

```
namespace {
    const rgb black(0.0,0.0,0.0);
}

rgb
Specular::f ( const HitRecord& hitrec, const Vector& wo, const Vector& wi ) const
{
    rgb L(0,0,0);
    float ndotwi = dot(hitrec.normal, wi);

    Vector r = -wi + 2.0 * hitrec.normal * ndotwi;
    float rdotwo = dot(r, wo);

    // reflection detected
    if ( rdotwo > 0.0 )
        L = ks_ * pow(rdotwo, exp_);

    return L;
}

rgb
Specular::rho ( const HitRecord& hitrec, const Vector& wo ) const
{
    return black;
}
```

in sphere.cpp

```
bool
Sphere::hit ( const Ray& ray, interval_t tmin, interval_t tmax, HitRecord& hitrec ) const
{
    Vector org = ray.origin() - center_;
    Vector dir = ray.dir();
    float a = dot(dir, dir);
    float b = dot(dir, org) * 2;
    float c = dot(org, org) - pow(radius_, 2);
    float discriminant = pow(b,2) - 4*a*c;

    if ( discriminant > 0 )
    {
        discriminant = sqrt(discriminant);
        double t = ( -b - discriminant ) / ( 2*a );

        if ( t < tmin )
            t = ( -b + discriminant ) / ( 2*a );

        if ( t > tmin and t < tmax )
        {
            // hit detected
            hitrec.t            = t;
            hitrec.hit          = true;
            hitrec.normal       = unify( t*ray.dir() + org );
            hitrec.material_ptr = material_ptr_;
            hitrec.hitpoint     = ray.origin() + t * ray.dir();
            hitrec.ray          = ray;

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

do you have ideas where the error could be caused? what are possible factors that lead to such results?

thanks in advance,
patrick.

Comment: Out of gamut spots on a reflective surface aren't particularly surprising to me. The canonical silver ball with a spot pointing at it from the side should have specular highlights that are brighter than bright.

Comment: Yes that's true, but normally the spot should get smaller if i increase the exponent. But it doesn't :(

Comment: I've been fooled by the 'reflection' tag, darn, expected .net reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem is that you have to unify the wo vector (in Phong::shade).